# For which positive integers $n$ and $m$ is $x^n \equiv x^m \space \text{(mod 3)}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*See edit...*

Is this a correct solution?

The problem:

> For which positive integers $n$ and $m$ is $x^n \equiv x^m \space
> \text{(mod 3)}$?

The solution is:

> $n - m$ should be an even integer.

Here is my reasoning:

If $x$ is divided by $3$ we get the following three cases: $x \equiv 0$, $x \equiv 1$, or $x \equiv 2$ So I write:

$x \equiv 0 \implies x^m \equiv 0^m \equiv 0\space \text{(mod 3)}$

$x \equiv 1 \implies x^m \equiv 1^m \equiv 1\space \text{(mod 3)}$

$x \equiv 2 \implies x^m \equiv 2^m \equiv 2^m\space \text{(mod 3)}$

I express $n$ in terms of $m$, like $n=2m$, $n=3m$ and so on. I test to see whether some of these $n$:s satisfy all of the three cases stated above.  First $n=2m$, when I  get to $x \equiv 2$, $n=2m$ is $2^{2m} \equiv 4^m \equiv 1^m \space \text{(mod 3)}$. So it does not work with $n=2m$.  I try with $n=3m$ and when I get to $x \equiv 2$,  $n=3m$ is $2^{3m} \equiv 8^m \equiv 2^m \space \text{(mod 3)}$, thus $n=3m$ works. So we have:

$3\mid x^{3m} - x^m$

I see that $3m - m = 2m$.  I substitute  $3m$ with $n$ and arrive at the answer $n - m = 2m$. Correct?

**Edit:**

Would this be a better answer?

Let $n>m$, then we have $3 \mid x^n -x^m \iff 3 \mid x^m(x^{n-m}-1)$. If $3 \mid x  \implies 3\mid x^m$  for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If $3 \nmid x $ then $ (x^{n-m}-1) := x^{2k} -1 =(x^k-1)(x^k +1)$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \notin A$ where $A = \left\{ {x : x = 3n, n \in \mathbb{Z}  }\right\} \implies 3 \mid x^{n-m}-1$. So if $n - m = 2k$ then $3 \mid x^n -x^m $ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z} \iff x^n \equiv x^m \space \text{(mod 3)}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Correct answer, proof could be better, but what is your real name?

Comment: The answer depends on $x$ though. Is the question "for which $n,m$ does this hold for all $x$"?

Comment: @Wojowu, yes it is for all $x$.

Comment: Just wondering. Is there a way to make the argument more concise?

Comment: Just judging by the last line of your proof, you do not have the correct answer. You don't need to have $n - m = 2m$, but only to have $n - m = 2k$, where $k \in \mathbb Z$. For instance, consider m = 20, n = 2.

Comment: @Mariuslp you are correct. So how do I use the fact that $3m - m = 2m$ to conclude that $n - m = 2k$?

Comment: You can't -- the premise of your proof was expressing $n$ in terms of $m$, ie $n = km$. You observed that it works when $k=2$, I guess you can observe it works too for any even $k$. But at the end, you still don't have explored all possibilities (m=18, n = 2 is still not covered by these cases). I would suggest looking at @Kontantinos Gaintanas' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n>m$. All you want to know is when $3\mid x^n-x^m$.
This equivalent to $3\mid x^m(x^{n-m}-1)$.
We have two cases: $3\mid x$ and $3\nmid x$.
If $3\mid x$ then $3\mid x^m$ for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$ so there is nothing actually you should be concerned about $n$ or $m$.
If $3\nmid x$ then $x^{n-m}-1$ should be a multiple of $3$. This can happen only if $n-m$ is an even number.
So, you could say that if $n-m=2k$ then $x^n\equiv x^m\pmod{3}$ for sure.

Comment: Why let $n>m$? Why not $m > n$? Is it because otherwise would $(x^{n-m})$ have a negative exponent?

Comment: @notmyrealname, the same argument works by symmetry.  You just need to consider $3 \mid x^m - x^n$ when $m > n$.